# rs.Read looping multiple times unexpectedly

Tags: vb.net, loops, listbox

In my project I have wrote a procedure to display all the members that have joined a specific class. When adding data to my listbox if there are 2 results returned these same two results will be added to the listbox multiple times, I would only like the results to be added once. Does anybody have an idea why my records are being added too many times?

```
Private Sub DisplayMembersOnClass(CurrentClassID As Integer)
    If CurrentClassID <> -1 Then
        If Dbconnect() Then
            Dim SQLCMD As New OleDbCommand
            With SQLCMD
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandText = "Select * " &
                    "From MembersClass,Class, Members " &
                    "Where MembersClass.ClassID = @CurrentClassID and Members.MemberID = MembersClass.MemberID"
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentClassID", CurrentClassID)
            End With
            Dim rs As OleDbDataReader = SQLCMD.ExecuteReader
            While rs.Read

                Dim firstname As String = rs("FirstName")
                Dim secondname As String = rs("SecondName")
                Dim MemberName = (firstname) & " " & (secondname)
                Dim DisplayValue As String = (MemberName) & " " & rs("Members.MemberID")
                Dim classitem As New ListBoxData(DisplayValue, & "ID - " rs("Class.ClassID"))

                ListBoxMembersOnClass.Items.Add(classitem)
            End While
            rs.Close()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: One idea would be that it is running more than one time.  There is no code there to clear the listbox.  Set a breakpoint to find out.  Note that databinding would be much easier than all that.  Please read [ask] and take the [TOUR]

Comment: Try running your query in SSMS and see what is returned. I am guessing that you are not getting what you expect.